# How to create a vector, where my x values (dx) are displayed in row 1 and my y values (dy) in row 2 in R

Tags: vector

I have a df with x and y positions and I would like to create a combined vector out of them (dx/dy) where the x value for each respective position is showed in row 1 and the y values in row two. Like this:

x1, x2, x3, x4 ...
y1, y2, y3, y4

I tried it the following way...

```
dx <- diff(table_str$xPos)
dy <- diff(table_str$yPos)
dt <- diff(table_str$time)

vec <- c(dx, dy)
```

how can I code this?
( sorry if this quesiton is stupid- I am completely new to R